# How can I check if a custom link created via Telegram API is used?

Tags: powershell, telegram

Can you please tell me how to check if a user has used a custom link created via Telegram API for a channel?

I create the link using this method:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/createChatInviteLink?chat_id=$($chat_id)&member_limit=1&name=$($invitelinkname)&expire_date='$expire_date_UNIX'"
```

I then send the resulting link to the user and save it to the database.

Is there any way to check via API that the link was used and `member_limit=1` was reached?

I use PowerShell.